# How to add ADF library in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, oracle-adf

I have use this [link](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/07/03/install-java-web-adf-netbeans-plug-in/) to install adf library,but i get this message:[image] .

I need help on installing and using ADF library.I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Eclipse with OEPE from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html) or [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-downloads-1861310.html) if you want to use it with Indigo, but I'd prefer to download the latest one.
In the second link you will also find at the end of the page the bundles so you can include it without the need to install Eclipse all over again.

You can start going by viewing [this video](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/oepe/Oepe-highlevel/Oepe-highlevel.html) and [this one](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/technology/products/enterprise-pack-for-eclipse/adf-dev/ADF_Development_in_OEPE.html).
If you want a hand written documentation, check [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E47843_02/12121/OEPUG/introduction.htm) for the latest documentation or [that one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/documentation/previous-oepe-docs-1970457.html) for previous releases (depending on which one you downloaded).

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK...i have download the zip archive from here(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html) but when i need to create a new server i don't know the WebLogic Home.I only download this arhive and i cannot find webLogic.How to find?

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way to do it, you can either work with Eclipse using OEPE plugin or JDeveloper

PS: The tutorial you are referring to is talking about ESRI ADF, which is not Oracle ADF Framework at all!!!

Comment: I know I can use the adf 4.0 with Netbeans but i do not know how to make it work.On,maybe I use Eclipse.Can you give me a good tutorial for use adf with Eclipse?

Comment: ADF 4.0 is way older than what we are currently using. For Eclipse please search on the net. I would recommend you to use JDeveloper for ADF development. Using Jdeveloper is quite like using Netbeans/Eclipse. You would have to familiarise yourself with different keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Blocked are you talking about ESRI ADF 4?
If you do, please accept my apology because I'm talking about Oracle ADF which is a J2EE Framework, you should edit your question and tag it ADF instead of oracle-adf, also it'll be helpful to tag it as ESRI as well

Comment: Sorry but I do not know what I want.Simple, I want to use these [tags](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/apirefs.111240/e17491/toc.htm) in Netbeans.So how do?If i wrote wrong the name of question then tell me to edit.I do not want to install another IDE, i just want to make a few examples with tags like <af:selectManyChoice>.

Comment: Okay this is oracle ADF, so the tag is right, but the tutorial you followed in your link above is talking about totally different thing, it's talking about ESRI ADF Arc GIS, which is something totally different.
And to answer your question You can use the tags but you will have to work it the hard way, meaning get the tld libraries, download ADF Essentials, create page definitions on  your own, package everything on your own, but IDE help you have either JDeveloper or Eclipse with OEPE, NetBeans doesn't have plugins for Oracle ADF

Comment: Ok,thanks...I have Eclipse IDE for Java Developers ,Version: Indigo Service Release 1.Can you give me a good tutorial from which to go?(And put your answer as ANSWER not as comment)